# Macro to repeat a command N times

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to write a macro such as the following:

```
putcharX(repeat, char)

==>

putcharX(5, '*');

==>

putchar('*');
putchar('*');
putchar('*');
putchar('*');
putchar('*');
```

Note: I'm not looking to use a `for/while/do` loop, but literally copy the command `n` number of times in the code. Is such a thing possible with the cpp?

Comment: This is literally why for loops exist. And at high optimization levels the compiler will unroll the loop for you, which means it will copy the contents 5 times, if that makes any sense for the program. This question is such an obvious "Why would you want to do it?" kind of thing.

Comment: Anyway, no. You cannot do this with a number. You could create a set of macros named `REPEAT2`, `REPEAT3` etc and do it that way.

Comment: @ZanLynx well, an example would be like using `strace` -- measuring how long something takes on my computer, so running `putchar` 10M times or so and seeing what the average time it takes. A loop would add at least two instructions for the `jmp` and `update` expression, wouldn't it? Example here: https://godbolt.org/z/f5nbjb.

Comment: Possible with a set of macros : `putcharX(N, CH);`  selectively calls `putcharX_256` with in turn calls `putcharX_128` which calls  `putcharX_64` .....  A tad ugly, but doable.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes, exactly. That was what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 No time to code it right now, but with 8 levels of nesting , makes for a _long_ code to compiler .  May break the compiler if  the upper bound of N is large.

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 If you're trying to benchmark CPU instructions you're better off using assembly. Also if the CPU is anything near modern it is almost a waste of time. Compare and branch instructions will fuse together invisibly and be predicted hundreds of cycles in advance. They become essentially free. Also if you created a program that was literally 10M putchar calls in a row the CPU instruction cache would become useless and you're measuring RAM bandwidth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot write "real" recursive statements in macros. the closest you can get is

```
#define putcharOne putchar('*')
#define putcharTwo putcharOne; putcharOne
#define putcharThree putcharOne; putcharOne; putcharOne


#include <stdio.h>



int main()
{
        putcharOne;
        putcharTwo;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks, and it can be used exponentially, i.e., `#define putchar16 putchar8; putchar8;`